# Text only radio buttons

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a series of radio buttons, whereby there are no radio buttons, only the labels and the selected "button" is indicated via a red, rounded border. This is to emulate a given paper form whereby a value is indicated by circling a single number.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but your probably going to need some javascript

Comment: Javascript is perfectly acceptable. I'm already using it to precalculate some of the values based on prior user data.

Comment: I mean Im not going to write code for you, if you have a jsFiddle, I can look at it.

Comment: I tinkered with my version a little.

Comment: @watson I should have probably been clearer I was just looking for a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: @Drakekin Thats cool, sorry, ive been in a bad mood today : (

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No scripting needed. Just CSS.

Here's a fiddle: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/Lrxo62d7/)

I don't know exactly what you want, but this is at least proof of concept.

**CSS**

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid 2px red;
}
input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;   
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    border: solid 2px green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" id="test" name="jeff"><label for="test">Pizza</label>
<input type="radio" id="test2" name="jeff"><label for="test2">Steak</label>
```

Comment: Just fyi for anyone that comes across this like I did, the fiddle links don't work anymore, but the code does work as expected.