# Text-only HTML radio buttons that are keyboard-navigable?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, accessibility

This thread ([Text only radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166664/text-only-radio-buttons)) provides a way to make radio buttons that show only text, surrounded by a border that changes color when the button is selected.

The problem is that keyboard navigation does not work in this setup. That's not surprising; it's hiding the radio button and displaying only the labels.

Is there a way to have text-only radio buttons that work with keyboard navigation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution I can think of without Javascript is to make the button invisible without using `display: none`, because it doesn't render the button and so you can't navigate it.

This can be done trough `opacity`. This will make it invisible, but it'll still be there on its spot. In order to make it not interfere with the other elements, you can set it to `position: absolute`. All troubles gone.

[image]

See:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 2px red;
}

input[type="radio"] {
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  border: solid 2px green;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="test" name="jeff">
<label for="test">Pizza</label>
<input type="radio" id="test2" name="jeff">
<label for="test2">Steak</label>
```

An addition as mentioned by [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892473/text-only-html-radio-buttons-that-are-keyboard-navigable/48892574?noredirect=1#comment84790886_48892574) is to use the [`.visuallyhidden`](https://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/) class instead of just using opacity. The compatibility might be better.

```
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  height: 1px; width: 1px; 
  margin: -1px; padding: 0; border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Opacity is one way, another would be the `visuallyhidden` class from https://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/

Comment: And you might want to extend the selector of your last rule by `input[type="radio"]:focus + label` - then left/right arrow navigation between the radio buttons to switch which is the checked one will work, too. Or maybe rather add a new rule with a different styling, so that the user can distinguish between checked and focus state.

Comment: I tried using the `top: -999999px` to add to the answer, but this made the page go all the way up when I changed the radio button. The visuallyhidden class might be better. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following W3C page describes a way to make custom radio elements using ARIA:

[ARIA radiogroup and radio Example](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20160317/examples/radio/radio.html)

You should not use any CSS trick with native radio elements as it could led to unexpected behaviour. For instance focusing a native `radio` element with a screenreader may not always display the focus indicator (outline) around the label, but around the checkbox, which is problematic for people with low vision if that checkbox has been hidden.