# How to arrange a Three radio buttons on a same line along with label?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am developing one page which is responsible for displaying cart items inside that i  developed one more form called Customer details it contains three radio buttons , I want those three radio buttons and labels on a same line [like this i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YLjA.png)  , How to place my three radio buttons and along with their label names on a same line .[like this i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvZmz.png) please help me to fix this issue

`Cart.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="second -section">
<div class="details-box">
        <input type="text" v-if="hide==true" class="initial-btn" placeholder="Customer Details" />
    </div>    
    <div v-if="hide==false" class="fill-details">
        <form class="address" >
            <h4 class="heading">Customer Details</h4>
            <div class="name">
                <input type="name" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,10}">
                <label>Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="name">
                <input type="text" required  >
                <label>Phone Number</label>
            </div>
            <div class="pin">
                <input type="text" required >
                <label>PinCode</label>
            </div>
            <div class="pin">
                <input type="text" required>
                <label>Locality</label>
            </div>
            <div class="address-block">
                <input  class="address" type="text"  required>
                <label>Address</label>
            </div>
              <div class="city-landMark">
                <input type="text" required >
                <label>City/Town</label>
            </div>
            <div class="city-landMark">
                <input type="text" required>
                <label>LandMark</label>
            </div>
            <div class="Radio-Buttons">
                <p>Type</p>
                <div class="radio-btns">
                 <input type="radio" id="Home" value="Home" name="Type" v-model="role">
                    <label for="Home" class="home-label">Home</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="Work" value="Work" name="Type" v-model="role">
                    <label for="Work" class="work-label">Work</label>
                     <input type="radio" id="Other" value="Other" name="Type" v-model="role">
                    <label for="Other" class="other-label">Other</label>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-continue">
            <button type="submit" class="continue" >continue</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>    
</template>
<style>
@import "colors";
.container{
    // background:#FFFFFF;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-left:177px;
    width:774px;
    height:241px;
    // border:1px solid #707070;
    // border-radius:1px;

}
.content{
    margin-left:177px;
    width: 155px;
    height: 22px;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal medium 18px/22px Lato;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: $light_black;
    opacity: 1;
}
.mid-section{
    display:flex;
}
.mid-section img{
    width: 105px;
    height: 85px;
    margin-top:40px;
    padding-left:36px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.title-section {
    margin-top:40px;
    padding-left:38px;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/17px Lato;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: $light_black;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 180px;
    height: 17px;
    font-weight:300;
}
.author-section {
    font: normal normal normal 12px/12px Lato;
letter-spacing: 0px;
color: #9D9D9D;
opacity: 1;
width: 63px;
height: 12px;
margin-left:141px;
margin-top:-58px;
}
.price-section{
    margin-left:141px;
    font: normal normal bold 15px/18px Lato;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: $light_black;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.price-section h6{
    font-weight:600;
}
.plus-btn{
    border-radius:45%;
    width: 24px;
height: 24px;
margin-left:141px;
}
.btn{
    position:absolute;
    width: 151px;
height: 35px;
background: #3371B5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
border-radius: 2px;
opacity: 1;
margin-top:-50px;
margin-left:800px;
font: normal normal medium 14px/17px Lato;
letter-spacing: 0px;
color: $pale_white;
text-transform: uppercase;
opacity: 1;
}
.close-btn{
    background:none;
    border:none;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:650px;
}
.fa-minus-circle{
    font-size: larger;
background:none;
border: 1px solid $grey_white;
opacity: 1;
margin-left:141px;
}
.fa-plus-circle{
    font-size: larger;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid $grey_white;
opacity: 1;
}
.icons .rectangle{
    width: 41px;
height: 24px;
}
.initial-btn{
    width: 774px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
    border-radius: 1px;
    font: normal normal normal 15px/18px Lato;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #333232;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left:177px;
    margin-top:5px;
}
.fill-details{
    width: 774px;
    height: 450px;
    background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
    border-radius: 1px;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left:177px;
    border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
}
.form{
    position: absolute;
   
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 25px;
    margin-left:177px;
}
.heading{
width: 185px;
height: 18px;
text-align: left;
font: normal normal normal 19px/18px Lato;
letter-spacing: 0px;
color: #333232;
opacity: 1;
padding-left:36px;

}
.address h4 {
    font-weight: 300;
}
.name  {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left:36px;
  

}
input[type="name"] {
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0 0 10px;
    width: 251px;
}
.name input[type="text"]{
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0 0 10px;
    width: 251px;
}
.pin input[type="text"]{
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0 0 10px;
    width: 251px;
    
}
.pin{
    padding-left:36px;
    margin-top:-35px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.city-landMark{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left:36px;
    margin-top:-35px;
}
.city-landMark input[type="text"]{
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0 0 10px;
    width: 251px;
}
.address-block input[type="text"]{
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0 0 10px;
    width: 550px;
    height:50px;
}
.address-block{
    padding-left:36px;
    margin-top:-35px;
    display: inline-block;
}
 .Radio-Buttons p{
    padding-left: 50px;
}
 #home-label{
 
    padding-top:50px;
}
.btn-continue{
    padding-left:550px;
}
.continue{

    width: 160px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #3371B5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 3px;
    opacity: 1;
    font: normal normal medium 14px/17px Lato;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 1;
}
.home-label{
    padding-left: 25px;
}
 form input {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left:177px;
}

input:focus {
    border: 1.5px solid #1f52f9;
}

 form label {
    position: relative;
    font-family: roboto;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 15px;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 20px;
    top: -28px;
    transition: .2s all;
}
input:focus~label,
input:valid~label {
    top: -49px;
    left: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #1f52f9;
}

</style>
```

Comment: This question answers your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166664/text-only-radio-buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have directly use the element selector by tag name instead by class or ID. So, other label element are also affected by that styling.

Please review your CSS code and give property to specific element by using class or ID or other selector instead of directly selecting by tag name.

I wrapped each radio buttons in a div and made those div a flexbox and gave them a gap to space out.

```css
.radio-btns{
  display: flex;
  gap: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-btns">
  
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="Home" value="Home" name="Type" v-model="role">
  <label for="Home">Home</label>
  </div>
  
  <div>
  <input type="radio" id="Work" value="Work" name="Type" v-model="role">
  <label for="Work" class="work-label">Work</label>
  </div>
  
    <div>
  <input type="radio" id="Other" value="Other" name="Type" v-model="role">
  <label for="Other">Other</label>
  </div>
  
</div>
```